# SSRS 2016 web rendering border issue

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016

Image on the left is rendered in SSRS 2014 on the web portal with a 1pt border created in Report Builder 3.

Image on the right is rendered in SSRS 2016 on the web portal with a 1pt border created in Report Builder 2016.

Same image is used in both reports.

Is it just me? Putting the image in a rectangle does not help. There is always whitespace on the right side and bottom side of the image rendered in 2016.

It seems it will render correctly in .pdf or MHTML, but on the web it causes the gap.

Can't seem to find any information on this.

[edit]: Clipping the image in 2016 seems to fix the border issue, but at original size the gap remains.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which Browser are you using? And what version?

Comment: Tested on IE 11.187.14393.0, Chrome 53.0.2785.116 and Edge 38.14393.0.0